# The analogue of Liouville's inequality in several variables

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-approximation

[Liouville's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(Number_Theory)) in Diophantine approximation asserts that for each irrational algebraic number $\alpha$ of degree $d$, we have
$$ |q\alpha - p| \gg_\alpha |q|^{1-d}$$
for all integers $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $q \neq 0$. (Here, $X \gg_\alpha Y$ if $X \geq C_\alpha Y$ for a constant $C_\alpha$ dependent only on $\alpha$.)

More generally, for an $n$-tuple $\vec \alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$ of algebraic numbers, if $1, \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then there exists $\delta = \delta(\vec \alpha) > 0$ such that we have the estimate
$$ \left| \sum_{i=1}^n q_i\alpha_i - p \right| \gg_{\vec \alpha} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |q_{i}|^{1-\delta}$$
for all integers $p,q_1,\dots,q_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $q_i \neq 0$ for at least one $i$. This is, for instance, a very special case of [Schmidt's Subspace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_theorem), and one can prove it by a more-or-less direct repetition of the proof of Liouville's Theorem.

Does the above statement have a name? (Alternatively, I'd also appreciate a reference that one can cite.)

(The reason why I'm asking is that I need the above statement in a paper, and referring to it as a consequence of the Subspace Theorem feels like using a cannon to kill a fly.)

Comment: Did you mean $1-d$ in the exponent of the first display? And no clue about a name! Maybe there’s a catchy way to say that nonzero norms of algebraic integers are at least $1$! No clue about a quick reference either…

Comment: @alpoge I did mean $1-d$, thank you! Corrected now.